# Solr Admin pages does not loaded

Tags: java, solr, admin

I am using Solr and I try to mount solr onto my webapp let said it is: MyApp.  According to the solr web.xml:

I modified it to be:

```
<filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter</filter-class>

<init-param>
  <param-name>path-prefix</param-name>
  <param-value>/solr/</param-value>
</init-param>
```

```
<filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/solr/*</url-pattern>
```

I also modified this part of mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LoadAdminUI</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/solr/admin.html</url-pattern>
```

I also copy the entire solr.war to the folder:  MyApp/solr/

so instead of going to /solr/admin.html I want to go to my webapp such as:
/MyApp/solr/admin.html

When it run, I can hit : /solr/admin.html, but the page won't load completely.
What do I miss? Please help. ...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this feature never made it into 4.0, and unfortunately even now isn't even on the radar for 4.3.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3781